# how to make a editor in web app for questions and answer system

Tags: web, editor

I am making a system in which, a user can write any questions and answer of that question, those question and answer include all maths  and science formulas and other symbols of any subject and its also include images those can be placed by a user in particular question or answer and formate that question or answer, so i am searching for editor or  some other idea which can help me, please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [codecogs](http://codecogs.com) editor, that's meet your need of web formula editor

Comment: Thank you for your answer , if you have another suggestion as well please guide me...